# Repositorio devuelve lectura nulo y genera un error en clase que recibe - Sprint Boot

Tags: mysql, spring, boot

Hice una consulta con JPA que dependiendo de los datos devuelve un valor nulo. Trato de obtener una diferencia de fechas en minutos y construí una clase para para captar el resultado. Realice pruebas visualizando los resultados por debug y la segunda interacción no encontró datos y por consiguiente la clase "Conteo" quedo con nulo y lógicamente me manda un error. Cómo hago para resolver esto?

**Mi clase que debe obtener el resultado**

```
public class Conteo {
    
    private int conteo = 0;
    
    public Conteo(int conteo) {
        this.conteo = conteo;
    }
    
    public Conteo() {
        this.conteo = 0;
    }

    public int getConteo() {
        return conteo;
    }

    public void setConteo(int conteo) {
        this.conteo = conteo;
    }
}
```

**El repositorio**

```
public interface TransaccionRepository extends CrudRepository<Transaccion, Long> { 
      
      @Query("SELECT new com.innova507.tempuswebserver.dao.Conteo(MINUTE(max(m.fechaTiempoGps)) -  MINUTE(min(m.fechaTiempoGps))) FROM Transaccion m WHERE m.usuario.usuarioId = ?1 AND m.fechaTiempoGps >= ?2 AND (m.velocidad >= ?3 AND m.velocidad <= ?4)")
      Conteo findByUsuarioFechaVelocidadConteo(Long usuarioId, Date fecha, float v1, float v2);

}
```

**El método que lo llama**

```
    public boolean detectoAlarma(Long usuarioId, int d, Date dt, float v1, float v2) {
        boolean r = false;
        Conteo c  = transaccion.findByUsuarioFechaVelocidadConteo(usuarioId, dt, v1, v2);
        if (c != null) {
            if (c.getConteo() >= d) {
                r = true;
            }
        }
        return r;
    }
```

Importante: Al ejecutar transaccion.findByUsuarioFechaVelocidadConteo(usuarioId, dt, v1, v2); se genera el error.

**El error**

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not instantiate class [com.innova507.tempuswebserver.dao.Conteo] from tuple; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not instantiate class [com.innova507.tempuswebserver.dao.Conteo] from tuple
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:384) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:246) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:488) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy111.findByUsuarioFechaVelocidadConteo(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.innova507.tempuswebserver.api.LocalizacionService.detectoAlarma(LocalizacionService.java:86) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.innova507.tempuswebserver.api.LocalizacionService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fbceb2fe.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) ~[spring-core-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:669) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at com.innova507.tempuswebserver.api.LocalizacionService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$84ea5ce4.detectoAlarma(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.innova507.tempuswebserver.websocket.TempusHandler.lambda$0(TempusHandler.java:86) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at com.innova507.tempuswebserver.websocket.TempusHandler.localizacionUsuarioTransaccion(TempusHandler.java:82) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.innova507.tempuswebserver.websocket.TempusHandler.handleBinaryMessage(TempusHandler.java:52) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.AbstractWebSocketHandler.handleMessage(AbstractWebSocketHandler.java:46) ~[spring-websocket-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.WebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(WebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:75) ~[spring-websocket-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(LoggingWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:56) ~[spring-websocket-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.handler.ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.handleMessage(ExceptionWebSocketHandlerDecorator.java:58) ~[spring-websocket-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.handleBinaryMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:120) [spring-websocket-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.access$100(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:42) [spring-websocket-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter$4.onMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:87) [spring-websocket-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.socket.adapter.standard.StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter$4.onMessage(StandardWebSocketHandlerAdapter.java:84) [spring-websocket-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.sendMessageBinary(WsFrameBase.java:582) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.sendMessageBinary(WsFrameServer.java:131) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processDataBinary(WsFrameBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processData(WsFrameBase.java:300) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.WsFrameBase.processInputBuffer(WsFrameBase.java:133) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.onDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:82) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.doOnDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:171) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFrameServer.notifyDataAvailable(WsFrameServer.java:151) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler.upgradeDispatch(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:148) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.upgrade.UpgradeProcessorInternal.dispatch(UpgradeProcessorInternal.java:54) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:53) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1457) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_281]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.20.jar:8.5.20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_281]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not instantiate class [com.innova507.tempuswebserver.dao.Conteo] from tuple
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1679) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:560) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:372) ~[spring-orm-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy145.getSingleResult(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:206) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:85) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:116) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:106) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:483) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:56) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.7.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136) ~[spring-tx-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    ... 44 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not instantiate class [com.innova507.tempuswebserver.dao.Conteo] from tuple
    at org.hibernate.transform.AliasToBeanConstructorResultTransformer.transformTuple(AliasToBeanConstructorResultTransformer.java:41) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.HolderInstantiator.instantiate(HolderInstantiator.java:75) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.getResultList(QueryLoader.java:469) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2429) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2424) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1326) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getSingleResult(QueryImpl.java:529) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 64 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
    at org.hibernate.transform.AliasToBeanConstructorResultTransformer.transformTuple(AliasToBeanConstructorResultTransformer.java:37) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 75 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta modificando lo siguiente:

```
@Query("SELECT new com.innova507.tempuswebserver.dao.Conteo(MINUTE(max(m.fechaTiempoGps)) -  MINUTE(min(m.fechaTiempoGps))) FROM Transaccion m WHERE m.usuario.usuarioId = :usuarioId AND m.fechaTiempoGps >= :fecha AND (m.velocidad >= :v1 AND m.velocidad <= :v2)")
Conteo findByUsuarioFechaVelocidadConteo(Long usuarioId, Date fecha, float v1, float v2);
```

Te recomiendo que te fijes en los tipos de datos que están en tu tabla vs lo que les estas pasando a nivel de código, estos deben ser equivalentes, ejemplo: varchar == String.
Saludos

Comment: Gracias por l comentario